# Flash security and proper development methods

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-media-server

In near future i'm going to develop a flash media server application when i'm asp.net developer. Currently i'm in research how i do things i need to. Basically i have two questions.

1.What is the secure method to write your application? In external .as files which cannot be accessed by IIS but the source code will be seen or just to compile full .swf with code and then use some external tool that encrypts whole file ie. Amayeta SWF Encrypt.

2.Probably i'm going to send secure data from client to server and responses from server to client, so client will have the source file which he can use to track down requests and responses so little bit of reverse engineering and he could trigger his own rules. What best way to avoid these things from your experience ? Maybe i should keep only parts i must to have in Flash and with the rest to deal using ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would'nt worry about the security of the actionscript code within the flash file.

I would go with option 2 where most of the work should be done on the server where flash is just used as the presentation layer, taking advantage of its rich UI. It should be written as "thin" as possible. Doing it this way also means you can experiment with Silverlight and ajax etc, which might suit your skills better?

Comment: Ok, Silverlight doesn't fit it.

So need to keep only UI on client side ?

Now, let's say i want to check the time of user, which will be crucial to the application. Let's say user user bought some credits and i need to check whether he still got the credit to continue. How i can make those checks on server side with AS1 ? I need to send some secure data ( to have some sort of condition) back to user and this is where the problem starts